# Android FFmpeg cant set quality of image

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am working with FFmpeg on Android, I am trying to extract frames from a video every second. I made this command that works well:

```
final String cmd[] = {

            "-i",
            videoPath,
            "-vf",
            "fps=1",
            mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() +
            "out%d.png"
    };
```

Now I want to reduce the quality of the extracted frames so I tried this but get the error:

```
final String cmd[] = {

            "-i",
            videoPath,
            "-vf",
            "fps=1",
            "-qscale:v 12",
            mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() +
            "out%d.png"
    };
```

> At least one output file must be specified

What is the problem? I have searched online a lot and cant find a solution to the problem, also is there a better  way to reduce the quality of my extracted frames?

thanks

Comment: Of course silly mistake thank you

Answer (score 0):

PNG is lossless and ignores `-qscale:v`.

Use JPG instead which accepts a `-qscale:v` range of 2-31 where a lower value is a higher quality.

Comment: I am getting this: ` Expected number for q: 5 but found: -i`

Comment: `{"-y", "-qscale: 5", "-i", data.getFile_path(), "-strict", "experimental", "-vf", altitudeString + latitude + appName + speed + value60 + value100 + longitude + time, removeAudio, "-vcodec","mpeg4", path}
` is the command I have used

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to solve it. `"-qscale:v", "5"` is the right way of calling it.

Comment: @TusharGogna You are attempting to apply `-qscale:v` as an input option, but it is an output option. Option order is important: `ffmpeg [input options] -i [output options] output`. You don't need `-strict experimental` unless your ffmpeg is really old.